# Wiring two 3-way switches with 2 light fixtures and 1 outlet

Tags: wiring

[image]
Can someone please tell me how to wire this I searched everywhere on the web and I found nothing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If this were the Physics SE, then I'd say that homework questions are off-topic. Not sure about here, though.

Comment: You are probably not going to find a direct answer.  The individual parts of the requirements should be found easily.  Looks like homework.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad.  This is a hypothetical question about an entire circuit that is not likely to be helpful to anyone outside of this class.  This site works better with questions focused on a single problem after some basic research of the problem has been done.  Also, there are tons of answered questions about 3 way switches and outlets.

Answer (score 1):

### Your teacher is wrong.  You *can't do that*.

Between the lamps you need **four** wires:

- Two travelers, since they need to go past  the lamps
- A switched-hot, since both lamps need switched-hot
- A neutral, since both lamps need neutral

That's **four** wires plus ground, all of which are part of the same subcircuit.

Since the four wires are related and part of the same subcircuit, they must be part of the same cable.  **Your instructor plans to use two 14/2 cables to provide the 4 conductors.  That is a violation of NEC 300.3(b), all related wires must be in the same cable**.  *Why? Eddy current heating and vibration causing fatigue breaks, we're dealing with AC here*.

### He also forgot neutral to the switch box

His installation violates 404.2(c), which requires neutral come to every switch box.  That is a NEC 2011 requirement to support "smart switches".

### So let's reboot this deal

Assuming these lights and switches are ~18" apart, this will not work with the segments of wire he specified.   However, this is how you do it.  I chose colors *by function* (red=switched hot, yellow=2 travelers).  Common cables may not come in those colors; whatever, that's what colored tape is for.

[image]

*This diagram omits ground because it doesn't require any thinking and it just clutters up the diagram.*

Note how you will have a single, /3 cable *between the switches*.  The /3 cable only needs to go between the switches.

Don't do one of the stupidest things you can do in a 3-way circuit, *running the messengers through the lamp boxes for no reason whatsoever*.  Having the /3 cable stop at the lamps *is useless*, and far worse, it obliges you to have 3 splices of 2 wires each, which adds a bunch of box fill (12-13.5 cubic inches) to a standard octagon box *that's already way too small for that*.  It is simply insane to do this.

Once you've reached the far switch, you **double back** on a different route,  with /2 cable to the lamps.

This assures we comply with 300.3b (all related wires together in same cable), avoids using expensive 14/4 cable, and complies with 404.2c (neutrals at switches).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to be able to comment, so I have to do this as an answer. @Harper has a nice diagram, but is missing something. The fourth wire, which is simply the ground wire. It is common place to find 14/3, or 12/3 etc wire bundles to have a black (typically hot), white (typically neutral), red (typically traveler), and bare copper (ground). His picture shows all but the ground.

Comment: I don't draw them because grounds don't require any amount of thought; you simply web all grounds.  And they tend to clutter the heck out of the diagram, like [this mess](https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/3-way-switch-wiring-diagrams.html).  You are correct that 14/3 and 12/3 usually has red white black bare, but that's a mere limitation of manufacturing, and no purpose is assigned except safety ground, and neutral *if present*.   All others are up for grabs, hence, my use of colored tape.

Comment: He was saying that when wiring in the order on the chalk board you _would need 4 wires:_ traveler, traveler, switched hot, neutral (and ground).  His diagram method only needs 3 wires (plus ground).

Comment: I was simply stating that more for the inexperienced who might be wondering why he mentions 4 wires and only show 3. @Harper, no offense intended. Now that read @JPhi1618; I completely overlooked 2 yellow travelers, and was being simpleminded and only counting colors :)

Comment: Yeah now that you mention it, grounds are not actually specified in the problem.  He simply says /3 cable, and *in in-wall wiring* that means black white red, without stating whether a ground is even present.  (it's a different deal in *cordage i.e flexible equipment cords*; there /3 is inclusive of ground, e.g. black white green).